# How to write a regex expression that returns ("26", "jan", "2014") from a given text

Tags: python, regex

given this text:

```
text_q2f = '169.237.46.168 - - [26/Jan/2014:10:47:58 -0800] \
"GET /stat141/Winter04/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2585 \
"http://anson.ucdavis.edu/courses/"'
```

I've tried various things but have not come close or kept any of them.

Comment: chech this `/(\d{1,2}([.\-/])[A-Za-z]{1,3}([.\-/])\d{1,4})/g`

Comment: “I've tried various things but have not come close or kept any of them.” What have you tried?

Comment: please check with this `/(\d{1,2})[-/]([A-Za-z]{3})[-/](\d{4})/` it will read in 3 groups. tested on JavaScript. you can see details [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=114930)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.search` to search for that pattern in your string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = re.search(r'[(\d{2})/([a-zA-Z]+)/(\d{4})', text_q2f)
>>> s.groups()
('26', 'Jan', '2014')
>>>
```

Comment: This can also match the URL if it follows the format. Recommend to create non-capturing groups to match before and after the date - or alternatively, only execute the regex on the first line of the string

Comment: this returns [('26', 'Jan', '2014')]. any idea how i can get it to return only ('26', 'Jan', '2014')? Thanks!